Multi-task learning-Loss function
0
I am training a convolutional autoencoder with two velocity fields (2D array) as inputs and outputs. These fields represent wind velocities in both the x and y directions within a square domain. My loss function is defined as Loss = Loss1 + w * Loss2
Loss1 = MSE between targets and outputs. Loss2 = MSE between the derivatives of U and V (components of velocity) in the target data and the derivatives in the outputs. I used the Sobel filter to calculate derivatives. I have two questions:
Q1) I noticed that when I train the model using only Loss1, the results are better compared to training with both Loss1 and Loss2. I initially expected that incorporating Loss2 would act as regularization and improve generalization. What could be the reason for this outcome?
Q2) Is it acceptable to calculate Loss1 using normalized data and Loss2 using actual (unnormalized) data? Or should both losses be computed using the same type of data?

Did you check how noisy the loss2 is? I can imagine that the derivatives (of something noisy) are quite peaky (high amplitudes)... Then the total loss is quite impacted by these peaks. Potentially pass the derivatives through a tanh or clipped function prior to computing loss2

Thank you for your response. I did check them. There is no peak on Loss 2.  But my loss values are huge, since I do not normalize my data.

If you combine losses in different scales into a scalar loss you need to have a reasonable big "coupling constant" lambda (which also has a unit) otherwise how would you add up something like meter^2+(millimeter meter/second)^2. Already unit wise this makes no sense :) so you loss will be loss1+lambda*loss2. Now the size of lambda itself needs to be optimized - it is a hyperparameter. I would start playing with it on a long scale and see if it has some effect
